# How to get Table(array)index in to component in Angular

Tags: html, node.js, angular, typescript

I made 2 dim-array to implement my data on html page,

```
<tbody>
   <tr *ngFor="let i of myarray2">
     <td  *ngFor="let j of i"> {{j}} 
     </td>
   </tr>
</tbody>
```

It looks like this:

[image]

I need a function like when I click the plus I want to pass index values of my array(i and j) into my component (.ts file).

Comment: Can you show us what you have tried so far to code these function?

Comment: i posted an alternative answer

Answer (score 0):

Set some additional variables to the `index` and use them in your (click) handler:

```
<tbody>
    <tr *ngFor="let subarray of myarray2; let i = index;">
        <td *ngFor="let item of subarray; let j = index;">
          {{item}}
          <span tabindex="0" (click)="someMethod(i, j)">+</button>
        </td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get as parameters with help of the comment.This one also works .Thanks a lot

html

```
 <tbody>
                            <tr *ngFor="let i of myarray2 ; let indx1 = index" [attr.data-index]="indx1">
                            <td  *ngFor="let j of i ; let indx2 = index" [attr.data-index]="indx2"  > {{j}} 
                            <button *ngIf="j=='0.0 h'" (click)="getIndexofTable(indx1, indx2)" class="fa fa-plus" > </button>
                             </td>

                        </tr>
```

typescript

getIndexofTable(index_value:number,index_value2:number){
}